# find the sum of array value

Tags: php, arrays, sum

i have a 3 dimensional array
example

```
arr[a][h][x] = 12
arr[a][p][x] = 12
arr[d][r][z] = 15
arr[a][f][x] = 12
arr[a][u][x] = 12
arr[b][q][y] = 19
arr[e][h][n] = 16
arr[f][h][n] = 14
---
---
```

using PHP, i need to find the sum of

```
arr[a][ANY][x]=?
```

where ANY - can have any value

```
( arr[a][p][x] + arr[a][h][x] + arr[a][f][x]+... )
```

also i need to find the sum of

```
arr[ANY][h][n]=?
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part in using a loop don't you understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $sum1 = 0;
    $sum2 = 0;  
    foreach($array['a'] AS $smallArray){
      $sum1 += $smallArray['x'];
    }

    foreach($array AS $smallArray){
      $sum2 += $smallArray['h']['n'];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $sum = 0;
 foreach ($arr['a'] as $a) {
      if (isset($a['x'])) {
           $sum += $a['x'];
      }
 }
```

That will work for the first one. A variation on that will work for the second one.

Comment: Love that you leave some work to the one asking the question aswell, upvote!